# what is n in nth:child selector in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am curious about nth child selector in css. But is hard to understand its logic for me now. Below given example highlight first and the last span.

```html
<div>
<span>This span is limed!</span>
<span>This span is not. :(</span>
<em>This one is odd. </em>
<span>Sadly, this one is not...</span>
<span>But this one is!</span>
</div>
```

```css
span:nth-child(2n+1) {
background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: You copied that out of the MDN?!

Comment: looks like an odd span selector.

Comment: why it is counting em in the list ?

Comment: @amit read my answer. It's counting the `<em>` as the 3rd child but since it's not a `<span>` it's not being highlighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`n` represents a natural number. Meaning, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...]`

In your CSS, `2n+1` thus means:
`2*0+1` (= `1`), `2*1+1` (= `3`), `2*2+1` (= `5`), `2*3+1` (= `7`) and so on.

Your code basically selects all the odd children. Which could be written much shorter, namely:

```
nth-child(odd)
```

Answer (score 4):

For first and last you can use the `span:first-child` and `span:last-child` selectors.

Regarding the nth-child, it is just repetitive selection of elemetns.
`span:nth-child(2n+1)` in example will select 1, 3, 5 etc... all the odd spans.

Answer (score 3):

In your specific example, it is selecting the odd elements as seen in the table below. Why is it counting the `<em>`? That's because as the name suggests, it is searching for a child of the parent `<div>` and in this case the `<em>` is the 3rd child of the parent but because it is not a `<span>` it is not highlighted.

`:nth-child` can use formulas, numbers, or certain keywords to select certain elements where `n` is the index an object has. Simply put, it's a very nice trick to have custom CSS options that follow a specific order or design without the need for having special classes and having to take into account when building HTML.

i.e. You wouldn't want to have have a special CSS classes for odd and even members when you can just use the `:nth-child` selector. Imagine if you're writing a table and color ever other line, if you have CSS classes, it will troublesome to add something to the middle of the table and change the CSS classes for the rows after to follow the odd/even pattern.

**Keywords**

```
:nth-child(odd)
:nth-child(even)
```

**Example Formulas (w/ an awesome ASCII table)**

As a description, the following table tells you the nth element that will be selected. For example, when you use the formula `2n+1` the 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th, 11th, ... elements will be selected.

```
n   2n+1    4n+1    4n+4    4n   5n-2  -n+3
0     1       1       4      -     -     3
1     3       5       8      4     3     2
2     5       9      12      8     8     1
3     7      13      16     12    13     -
4     9      17      20     16    18     -
5    11      21      24     20    23     -
```

**Resources**

[:nth-child in-depth](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

[Useful :nth-child Recipes](http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

[A nice visual tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

> The `:nth-child(an+b)` pseudo-class notation represents an element
>   that has `an+b-1` siblings before it in the document tree, for any
>   positive integer or zero value of `n`, and has a parent element. For
>   values of a and b greater than zero, this effectively divides the
>   element's children into groups of a elements (the last group taking
>   the remainder), and selecting the bth element of each group. For
>   example, this allows the selectors to address every other row in a
>   table, and could be used to alternate the color of paragraph text in a
>   cycle of four. The a and b values must be integers (positive,
>   negative, or zero). The index of the first child of an element is 1.

So, now what's the meaning of `span:nth-child(2n+1)` will represent every odd number of element, simple explanation, add 2 to every 1, so if the equation is like [`(3n+2)`](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFTb/4/) so it will be like 2, 5, 8 etc.. where `2n+0` OR just `2n` will represent even...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFTb/) (Odd) `span:nth-child(2n+1)`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFTb/1/) (Even) `span:nth-child(2n+0)` OR `span:nth-child(2n)`

---

We also have a pseudo, which is `nth-of-type` which is nothing but same thing in general, but you can take it as a stricter selector, `nth-child` will select **ANY TYPE OF ELEMENT** where as `nth-of-type` will select **THAT PARTICULAR ELEMENT**.

So, say you want to target 2nd `span` element, but your 2nd element in the DOM is not `span` but `p`, so the selector will simply fail if you use `nth-child`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFTb/2/)

Where as using `nth-of-type` will select your 2nd `span` and will just skip off the `p`

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4aFTb/3/)